# Is it possible to convert or migrate existing wcf application to .Net Core

Tags: wcf, .net-core

I have a wcf application and i want to **migrate it to .net core**. Anyone please suggest is there any way to migrate wcf to .net core, please suggest

Comment: Client side only, server side as well? Which bindings/transport/security-options do you require, any custom extensions, etc. Not everything is supported and  [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF) has not everything ported yet (and may never will).  Generally, Microsoft recommends using gRPC on the way forward - which depending on your application can be a huge undertaking to port to. Search the web for "WCF .NET core" for a variety of general guidelines, alternatives, etc. Or provide more details on your specific scenario.

Comment: I want to convert the WCF service , all its binding and code. I am using **basicHttpBinding**.  Its a simple application that just get the data from the application where the wcf service is consumed and  save the data into the DB this is what it does.

Comment: .Net core does not support WCF server-side, only WCF client-side. You can migrate WCF client-side to .Net core

Comment: @Dingpeng: Ok thank you , now i decided to  go to web api core